# Is the substitution given the question incorrect?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Show that an equation of the type $$u_{t}+6uu_{x}+u_{xxx}+a'(t)u_{x}=0$$ can be transformed into the KdV equation ($u_{t}+6uu_{x}+u_{xxx}=0$) by the transformation $$\begin{cases} \xi = x+a(t) \\ \tau =t \end{cases}$$

Note: I assume the expected substitution to be $u=v(\xi,\tau)$, by chain rule for multivariable functions it is easy to deduce $2a'(t)v_{\xi}+(v_{\tau}+6vv_{\xi}+v_{\xi \xi \xi})=0$ which is not yet the KdV equation for $v$.
I suspect the subsititution needs to be $$\begin{cases} \xi = x-a(t) \\ \tau =t \end{cases}$$, otherwise the original equation would be changed to $u_{t}+6uu_{x}+u_{xxx}-a'(t)u_{x}=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The substitutions  $$\begin{cases} \xi = x-a(t) \\ \tau =t \end{cases}$$ reduce the equation to $u_{t}+6uu_{x}+u_{xxx}=0$. Indeed calculating 
$u_x=u_\xi, u_{xx}= u_{\xi\xi},  u_{xxx}=u_{\xi\xi\xi}$ and $u_t=u_\xi\xi_t+u_\tau\tau_t=-a'(t)u_\xi+u_\tau$
and substituting into the equation we have

$u_t+6uu_x+u_{xxx}+a'(t)u_x=-a'(t)u_\xi+u_\tau+6uu_\xi+u_{\xi\xi\xi}+a'(t)u_\xi
=u_\tau+6uu_\xi+u_{\xi\xi\xi}$.

Answer (score 1):

Since the general solution of $u_t+a'(t)u_x=0$ is $u(x,t)=f(x-a(t))$ and not $u(x,t)=f(x+a(t))$ , therefore we let $\begin{cases}\xi=x-a(t)\\\tau=t\end{cases}$ and not let $\begin{cases}\xi=x+a(t)\\\tau=t\end{cases}$ for solely eliminating the term $a'(t)u_x$ of the PDE.